# Selecting lowest n values in from attribute table in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute

I have a shapefile with a "Random Number" Column. I'd like to use ModelBuilder to Select and export the lowest N values. I've seen this post about selecting the top 10 records which is pretty similar.

[Selecting limited TOP n from specific column in ArcGIS query builder?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82913/how-to-select-an-limited-top-n-from-a-specific-column-in-arcgis-query-builder)

But the problem I'm having is this post uses a Query Builder, but I'm not sure how to adapt this for model builder into the 'Select tool'. I'm using ArcGIS desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the data through the [SORT](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/sort.htm#L_) tool, sorting by your random number field, sorting in an ascending sequence, send the output into IN_MEMORY.

For example input data is:

[image: Initial data]

The sort tool creates an FID field which is sequential, so all you need to so is select rows where FID <= 10 as shown below:

[image: Sorted, lowest 10]

If you need the lowest 20 then select FID <= 20. This can all be easily included into a model.