# Labeling only the latest feature

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, labeling

I need to label only the latest feature in a particular feature class. I actually would like to automate it, so that when I will add any new feature to this feature class, the label will automatically be assigned to the latest one. Could anyone please help me with line of code?

Comment: Since you are adding a feature, it will have the highest FID. Accordingly, all you should need to do is get the number of features (possibly subtracting 1).

Comment: Using ArcGIS 10.1

Comment: What type of geodatabase is your feature class stored in?  Please use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with this detail.

Comment: you could use a TOP 1 query on a second layer based on the FID. see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53948/select-top-5-most-items-in-a-geodatabase  (DESC to reverse the sorting)

Answer (score 1):

Pushkar, I have done the following to answer this question using OBJECTID in a File Geodatabase and it works for me:   Within the labeling tab in the layer properties - choose method of *Define classes of features and label each class differently*  Then within the SQL use the following:

```
"OBJECTID" = (SELECT MAX("OBJECTID") FROM feature_class_name)
```

Then you can just set your label field to the field you want and only the largest OBJECTID will label.

Comment: @Pushkar if that works for you - please click the check mark beside my answer.  Thanks!